# Leitor sintático (Extensão do Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, parser

Ao fazer a leitura sintática de uma linguagem em um projeto de extensão do Visual Studio eu já consigo ler o seguinte:

```
<span class="myclass"></span>
```

É relativamente fácil gerenciar os estados de leitura `InTag`, `AttributeNaming`, `AttributeValue` (criei estes estados). Fazer a correta aplicação de cores pela classe Colorizer e tudo mais.

O problema:

O Visual Studio através de sua API me envia o código linha por linha esperando que eu devolva os tokens lidos. Como eu faço para ler uma linha quebrada?

```
<span
      class="myclass"></span> <!-- Meu parser verá erros e textos apenas -->
```

Há alguma forma de agrupar estas linhas? 
O outlining de código ajuda nestes casos? Como faço para utilizá-lo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso por exemplo, lendo uma linguagem mais complexa, como eu poderia criar o outlining e indetificar os estados? A; No namespace, B: declaração de nome de classe, C: na classe, D,: declarção de método, E: Nome de método, F: Corpo do método, por exemplo.

Comment: Legal isso aí, hein? Está escrevendo em código aberto?

Comment: é um projeto de extensão do próprio Visual Studio, usando sua própria SDK.

Answer (score 1):

No seu *parser*, se você estivar utilizando expressão regular para identificar os *tokens* e C#,  você deve habilitar a opção *Multiline* (m) ao executar o *match* dos *tokens* de acordo com o seu padrão.

Já precisei criar alguns *parsers* e sempre tive vários problemas básicos, então, encontrei a ferramenta [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Essa ferramenta gera parsers a partir de uma gramática. Talvez, no seu caso, seja mais fácil escrever a gramática do que você precisa identificar e fazer com que o ANTLR gere o *parser* para você.

O Bundle do ASP.NET MVC utiliza o ANTLR para interpretar javascript e css e minificá-los. Então, essa é uma ferramenta confiável e, digamos que, "bem testada".

Comment: Agradeço a resposta @Maia mas a questão não é como fazer o parser e sim como trabalhar com a extensão para ler múltiplas linhas, pois eu apenas implemento uma interface... e um de seus métodos me traz o código "linha por linha"